# managing digital certificates for email (postfix/dovecot) and DKIM

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, dkim

I am seeking to make emails my server sends have a higher reputation by implementing DKIM and DMARC.  I already am passing SPF with the proper DNS entries.

I also have a working Postfix/Dovecot installation with TLS turned on, but the certificates are just to the `snakeoil.crt/.pem` files found in `/usr/ssl` that came with my server setup.

My question is about the certificate I want to use.  I only have experience setting up a **signed** digital certificate for a domain name for a website.  Can I get another **signed** certificate and use it BOTH for Postfix/Dovecot TLS as well as the DKIM key?  Is it possible to use the same signed certificate for my website, Postfix/Dovecot and DKIM?  Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If the domain names used for mail and web are the same or if the certificate includes all the used names, then you can use the same certificate as server certificate for the web server and the mail server.

With DKIM the situation is different: it does not use a certificate but just an RSA key. Provided that your certificate is an RSA certificate you could use the key you have for the certificate for DKIM too.

Of course, there is always a tradeoff. If you use the same certificate or key for multiple services you increase the risk of compromise in case one of these services has bugs. On the other side it makes key management simpler, which again could increase security.